# StreamWriter stops writing when file is opened from web link

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, filestream, streamwriter

Following on from my previous question...

The following code creates log files on a web server:

```
private void LogMessage(Message msg)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(_logDirectory + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHH") + ".txt"))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
    }
}
```

The log files are linked to from an admin page on the web site:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in logDir.GetFiles())
{
    Response.Write("<a href='http:// .... /Logs/" + file.Name + "'>" + file.Name + "</a>");
}
```

I'm getting the problem that after someone looks at one of the log files from the link, that log file stops being written to.

Comment: Looks like a bad case of Notenoughinformationitis.

Comment: Are there any exceptions being thrown?  can you wrap it in a Try/catch and email or store the exception message to windows event log?  can you put a break-point to the problem area and step through and see if values are normal, no nulls or empty data?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the try catch, did you try to:

- Check for file == null
- InitializeLifetimeService
- AutoFlush